# use javascript or jQuery to open an excel file after download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

when i export excel file from my web application, i need to open it directly by default program after download.

html:

```
<a onclick="fnExcelExport();">Export As File</a>
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

javascript:

```
function fnExcelExport() {
var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
var textRange; var j = 0;
tab = document.getElementById('tablee'); // id of table
for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
    tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
}
tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); 
in your table
tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  
{
    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
}
else                 
    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
return (sa);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Are there errors?

Comment: It should be `text/html` not `txt/html`.

Comment: javascript and jquery are long forgotten by the time the file is downloaded. Any code that does that needs to be executed by client's OS, either through batch/bash, or through some server side language like python, nodejs, etc. that runs *on client side*

Comment: no error, i need to open it directly by default program after download.